# Knockout Input ReadOnly State

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to add a simple functionality in my program and Im having a little trouble figuring out how to do something I wanted. 
 
Here's what I got: 
 
My input textbox, with a link beside it to disable/enable readonly property on that input textbox.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { 'readonly': getreadonlyState() }" value="420" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: readonly">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Here's my knockout script for it:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.getreadonlyState = ko.observable('readonly');
    self.readonly = function() {
        if (self.getreadonlyState()) {
            self.getreadonlyState(undefined);
        }
        else self.getreadonlyState('readonly');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

This works great, but what I wanted is when I click the edit link, it will change the text of the link to something like: "Stop Editing" so when I click "Stop Editing" the readonly property is enabled again. 
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeTjS/81/) of what Im working on. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative to @thangcao's answer. I'm not saying this is any better or worse, simply an alternative which uses a *subscribe* handler instead of a *computedObservable*.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { 'readonly': getreadonlyState() }" value="420" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: readonly, html: linkText"></a>
</div>

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.getreadonlyState = ko.observable('readonly');
    self.getreadonlyState.subscribe(function(val) {
        self.linkText(val === "readonly" ? "Edit" : "Stop editing");
    });
    self.readonly = function() {
        if (self.getreadonlyState()) {
            self.getreadonlyState(undefined);
        }
        else self.getreadonlyState('readonly');
    }
    self.linkText = ko.observable("Edit");
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Notice that there's no need for the additional `<span>` in @thangcao's answer.

Also, why is the "edit"/"stop editing" element an anchor tag? Why not just make it a `<span>` and do away with the need for the additional inline JavaScript (which you can anyway replace with a `return false;` inside the `readonly` function).

[http://jsfiddle.net/ajameson/eeTjS/87/](http://jsfiddle.net/ajameson/eeTjS/86/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer but maybe you can help me with another problem that came up after I applied this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066669/knockout-add-and-edit-observablearray-conflict

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your Fiddle and hope that it meets your need:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { 'readonly': getreadonlyState() }" value="420" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: readonly"><span data-bind="text:linkText"></span></a>
</div>

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.getreadonlyState = ko.observable('readonly');
    self.readonly = function() {
        if (self.getreadonlyState()) {
            self.getreadonlyState(undefined);

        }
        else { 
            self.getreadonlyState('readonly');

        }
    }
    self.linkText = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.getreadonlyState() == 'readonly' ? "Stopping edit" : "Edit";
    }, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this binginHandlers :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.readOnly = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            element.setAttribute("disabled", true);

        } else {
            element.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }
};
```

In my html :

```
<input type="text" id="create-finess" class="form-control" data-bind="readOnly: _locked" />
```

Finaly in my JS :

```
//Constructor of my view model

  function ViewModel(resx) {
       this._locked = ko.observable();
}

  // on init of the page i lock the input
 this._load = function () {
  this._locked(true);
}
```