# Knockout Add and Edit observableArray Conflict

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observableArray which is displayed in a table using foreach binding where values are displayed inside textboxes. Now what I want to do is to add an edit link on each row which enables/disables the readonly state of the corresponding textbox in its row. I can do it, but the way I did it messed up my add new line (push) functionality.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/supermaynard05/r4vwLdtq/3/) of my code.

Try to delete a line then add it again by selecting it in the dropdown list, the edit link disappears as well as the value.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

So here's my HTML:

```html
<table class="input-group" >
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: loanDeductions">
        <tr>
            <td><strong data-bind='text: deductionName'></strong></td>
            <td><input class="deductionCode form-control" style="text-align: right" data-bind='value: amount, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown", attr: { "readonly": getreadonlyState() }' /></td>
            <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Delete</a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $parent.readonly"><span data-bind="text: linkText"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><select data-bind="options: loanDeductionsList(), optionsText: 'deductionName', optionsCaption: 'Choose a deduction..', value: selectedDeduction"></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now here is my script:

```
var deductionLine = function (deductionID, deductionName, amount) {
    self = this;
    self.deductionID = ko.observable(deductionID);
    self.deductionName = ko.observable(deductionName);
    self.amount = ko.observable(formatCurrency(amount));
    self.getreadonlyState = ko.observable('readonly');
    self.linkText = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.getreadonlyState() == 'readonly' ? "Edit" : "Stop Edit";
    }, self);
};

var deductionList = function (deductionID, deductionName, amount) {
    self = this;
    self.deductionID = ko.observable(deductionID);
    self.deductionName = ko.observable(deductionName);
    self.amount = ko.observable(formatCurrency(amount));
};

function LoanDeductions(deductions) {
    var self = this;
    self.loanDeductions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(deductions, function (deduction) {
        return new deductionLine(deduction.deductionID, deduction.deductionName, deduction.amount)
    }));
    self.loanDeductionsList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(deductions, function (deduction) {
        return new deductionList(deduction.deductionID, deduction.deductionName, deduction.amount)
    }));

    self.selectedDeduction = ko.observable();

    //edit link

    self.readonly = function () {
        if (BossBaU) {
            if (this.getreadonlyState()) {
                this.getreadonlyState(undefined);
            }
            else {
                this.getreadonlyState('readonly');
            }
        }
        else alert('Access denied!');
    }

    // adds deduction 
    self.selectedDeduction.subscribe(function (data) {
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.loanDeductions(), function (deduction) {
            return deduction.deductionID() === data.deductionID();
        });
        if (match) {
            alert(data.deductionName() + ' already exists!');
            self.showAddDeduc(false);
        } else {
            self.loanDeductions.push({
                deductionID: data.deductionID,
                deductionName: data.deductionName,
                amount: data.amount,
            });
            self.showAddDeduc(false);
        }
    });

    //delete deduction
    self.removeLine = function (line) { self.loanDeductions.remove(line) };

};

var viewModel = new LoanDeductions(@Html.Raw(Model.CRefLoansDeductions2.ToJson()));
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle contains code different from that in your question. Have you considered using Stack Snippets? Also, the fiddle just plainly gives a script error, have you debugged it yet? What were your results?

Comment: You keep forgetting the `var` keyword at your `self = this;` lines. This is a serious problem you need to fix.

Comment: @Tomalak thank you, I didnt notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *subscribe* handler, `self.selectedDeduction.subscribe`, you're adding an object to the list of `loanDeductions` when you should be adding a new instance of `deductionLine` just as you do when you declare `self.loanDeductions`.

Or to put it another way, `self.loadDeductions` is an observableArray of `deductionLine` instances, to which you then add an object with three properties.

Change that *subscribe* handler to push a `new deductionLine(...)` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem, I had to mirror every changes I made with my observableArray to my list.

```
var deductionLine = function (deductionID, deductionName, amount) {
    self = this;
    self.deductionID = ko.observable(deductionID);
    self.deductionName = ko.observable(deductionName);
    self.amount = ko.observable(amount);
    self.getreadonlyState = ko.observable('readonly');
    self.linkText = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.getreadonlyState() == 'readonly' ? "Edit" : "Stop Edit";
    }, self);
};

var deductionList = function (deductionID, deductionName, amount) {
    self = this;
    self.deductionID = ko.observable(deductionID);
    self.deductionName = ko.observable(deductionName);
    self.amount = ko.observable(amount);
    self.getreadonlyState = ko.observable('readonly');
    self.linkText = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.getreadonlyState() == 'readonly' ? "Edit" : "Stop Edit";
    }, self);
};
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4vwLdtq/4/) in case anyone bump into a similar issue.